# How do you write tests for checking vars of a specific type?

Tags: go, testing

I have a function that returns a specific type of client and I want to test the function by checking if the type of the variable returned is of the type `azblob.BlockBlobClient`.

When I use a simple `if` statement to check the type like this: `if var == azblob.BlockBlobClient` I get the error `azblob.BlockBlobClient (type) is not an expression`

What's the proper way to test for variable types with the standard `testing` package?

Much thanks in advance!

**//func**

```
func getClient(blob, container string) azblob.BlockBlobClient {
  storageAccount := os.Getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME")
  
  cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("Invalid credentials with error:" + err.Error())
  }

  blobUrl := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s", storageAccount, container, blob)
  fmt.Println(blobUrl)
  client, err := azblob.NewBlockBlobClient(blobUrl, cred, nil)
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("Unable to create blob client")
  }
  return client
}
```

**//test**

```golang
package main 

import (
    "testing"
    "os"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob"
)

func TestgetClient(t *testing.T){
  blob := "text.txt"
  container := "testcontainer"
  os.Setenv("AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME", "mystorageaccount")
  client := getClient(blob, container)
  
  if client != azblob.BlockBlobClient {
    t.ErrorF("Client should be type BlockBlobClient")
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly your goal, you have noting to do :-) Go is a statically typed language, since the return type of getClient is azblob.BlockBlobClient, it is the compiler that will type check.

Comment: Oh! hahah that's the advantage of a compiled language. My apologizes, Go's my first compiled language and that shows in my question. :) Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: No problems! You are in for many pleasant surprises! Just try to "swim with the flow" of Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to do this because the function you have wrote only returns the `azblob.BlockBlobClient` type, the compiler will check this before even building the tests. The test would fail to run if this was not the case.

I made the following changes to show this:

#### //func

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob"
)

func getClient(blob, container string) interface{} {
    storageAccount := os.Getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME")

    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Invalid credentials with error:" + err.Error())
    }

    blobUrl := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s", storageAccount, container, blob)
    fmt.Println(blobUrl)
    client, err := azblob.NewBlockBlobClient(blobUrl, cred, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to create blob client")
    }
    return client
}
```

#### //test

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob"
)

func TestgetClient(t *testing.T) {
    blob := "text.txt"
    container := "testcontainer"
    os.Setenv("AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME", "mystorageaccount")
    client := getClient(blob, container)

    _, ok := client.(azblob.BlockBlobClient)
    if !ok {
        t.Errorf("client should be type BlockBlobClient")
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes total sense, thank you for the explanation and updated example. That helped it click in my head. :)